# Customized Number Format in Excel

Tags: excel-2010, business-intelligence, measurement, powerpivot

Goal:
Retrieve the requested result from the "Requested value".

```
Current & normal value | Requested value
----------------------------------------
320                    |             320
8256                   |           8,256
159                    |             159
10456789               |      10,456,789
2321654,75             |       2,321,655
201987,5               |         201,988
5321877                |       5,321,877
```

Problem:
How should I do it in order to gain a number format that is similiar as in the "Requested value" in Excel?

- The current value I have is "Current & normal value"
- I'm retrieving data from data mart and paste it into a excel dokucment with PowerPivot.
- The value is used as a measurement and more different mesurement will be used so if it possible to reuse the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the numeric/values elements of PowerPivot it's good practice to explicitly create them as measures. e.g. if your number is the sum of the sales column you would write:

```
[Sales Measure] = SUM('table1'[Sales])
```

One of the options you will get when creating the measure is to format the number and while it isn't as comprehensive as standard Excel, you can achieve the 'requested value' format you indicate above.

HTH
Jacob